# Assistance with refactoring a LINQ method

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am in need of some assistance, I have a method which is repeated 6 times in my class, and the only thing that changes in each of the methods is the LINQ property (in the example "first name", but I also have one for last name, firm name, user id, status).  I would like some help refactoring this so that I can use just one method and make the property to be dynamic or passed in.

```
private static IQueryable<MyModel> FilterFirstName(IQueryable<MyModel> query, string searchText, string searchFilter)
    {
        switch (searchFilter.ToLower())
        {
            case "contains":
                query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
                break;
            case "does not contain":
                query = query.Where(x => !x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
                break;
            case "starts with":
                query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
            case "ends with":
                query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.EndsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
            case "equals":
                query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName.Equals(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
        }

        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Is it always a string property?

Comment: yes, it is always a string property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use a `Compose` method that can compose one expression with another:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Which uses the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
private static IQueryable<MyModel> FilterFirstName(
    IQueryable<MyModel> query,
    Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> selector,
    string searchText,
    string searchFilter)
{
    switch (searchFilter.ToLower())
    {
        case "contains":
            query = query.Where(selector.Compose(
                text => text.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())));
            break;
        case "does not contain":
            query = query.Where(selector.Compose(
                text => !text.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())));
            break;
        case "starts with":
            query = query.Where(selector.Compose(
                text => text.StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
            break;
        case "ends with":
            query = query.Where(selector.Compose(
                text => text.EndsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
            break;
        case "equals":
            query = query.Where(selector.Compose(
                text => text.Equals(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
            break;
    }

    return query;
}
```

On a side note, you should really use an `enum` to represent the different types of filters for `searchFilter`, rather than a string.  It will make it much easier on the caller, as they won't need to type out an exact string without having any good way of knowing what the exact options are, or if the provided option is valid.

Comment: @Madhatter5501 Provide a lambda that projects the item in the list into a string value, presumably by accessing a property of it in most cases (although it could do whatever).  Other than the one added parameter, the rest is all the same.

Comment: This is essentially PredicateBuilder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) which is a much more complex solution than what is required.  I think @Madhatter5501 just needs to pick an individual property off the object, not compose arbitrary queries.

Comment: @MobyDisk PredicateBuilder is for composing *predicates*.  These aren't predicates.  LINQKit is a more general case implementation in which it allows expressions to be composed regardless of their signatures, and in a different syntax.  It could work here, but it would require a much larger and complex tool than the much smaller special case I have outlined here.  Were he already using LINQKit, he could use that instead.  Rather than have him install an entire library with a lot of complex code, I choose to instead provide the one page's worth that's just needed to do what he wants.

Comment: And with that, OP was able to query IQueryables with strings.

Comment: @moarboilerplate While that's true for the comparison operator, that's not the case for the selector.  The design here is to be able to specify different aspects of the query in different places.  One place statically defines a selector, another statically defines how to filter a query given a selector.  These pieces, each of which are providing a certain static implementation and that can be statically evaluated for validity, can then be composed dynamically in various ways that the type system can prove are safe.  It's the ability to make certain things dynamic in statically valid ways.

Comment: @Servy whether this whole layer is a giant smell or if OP really needs a dynamic selector depends on the problem that OP is trying to solve with these methods, which he hasn't provided. My instinct says this is a custom layer of "user-friendly queries" over LINQ, but I can't say for sure without added context.

Comment: @moarboilerplate If there's an end user somewhere that's specifying, based on options in a user interface, which column they want to filter on and which type of comparision should be used (something I've both seen done and done myself) then writing the queries entirely statically is approximately impossible.  The number of 100% static queries needed to handle all of those operations is N x M, where N is the number of fields to filter on and M is the number of comparison operations.

Comment: @Servy On the other hand, you may have just handed OP a bazooka with very little training. Like I said, it all depends on his implementation, which we can only make assumptions about.

Comment: @moarboilerplate So your response to the situation is to basically tell the OP to give up and not actually do what he needs to do?  I mean that's more or less what your answer is saying, because your proposal of doing everything statically is, for all intents and purposes, not possible.

Comment: @Servy it's not impossible, because *OP already has written everything out statically*. Ripping it out would only be removing an extra layer of indirection. The only increase in static calls due to inlining would be due to several areas of code calling the same combination repeatedly, which again requires another assumption.

Comment: @Madhatter5501 I'm sure it works, the question is whether this layer needs to exist. If you really do need to select a field dynamically, and have it translated into an EF query, a) please don't hesitate to mention that, and b) there are other alternatives, like parameterized queries against your DbContext.

Comment: would this answer completely have changed if I hadn't made the class static?  I am a new developer so some of this is a little over my head, but the help I get on here is awesome.  I am not using entity framework, but using a stored procedure and a List of my entity class, then I am using linq to apply filtering.

Comment: @Madhatter5501 I think it would have gone a long way to provide some context with how you were calling it, but no harm done. Now that we know you're not using EF and that you're using a stored procedure, we have more context.

Answer (score -1):

This version allows you to pass a property to the filter, like this:

```
Filter(models, (MyModel m) => m.FirstName, "Joe", "contains"); 
Filter(models, (MyModel m) => m.LastName, "Smith", "contains"); 

private static IQueryable<MyModel> Filter(IQueryable<MyModel> query, Func<MyModel, string> property, string searchText, string searchFilter)
{
    switch (searchFilter.ToLower())
    {
        case "contains":
            query = query.Where(x => property(x).ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
            break;
        case "does not contain":
            query = query.Where(x => !property(x).ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
            break;
        case "starts with":
            query = query.Where(x => property(x).StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            break;
        case "ends with":
            query = query.Where(x => property(x).EndsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            break;
        case "equals":
            query = query.Where(x => property(x).Equals(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            break;
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: No query provider will be able to translate that into SQL; they'll all error when you try to execute the query.  Also, there's no need to explicitly specify the type of the lambda when calling the method; it will be inferred.

Comment: Oooooohh, good point about the query provider.  I tested it with a locally defined List.  tou·ché.

Answer (score -1):

I would do one or more of the following:

1. Reflection and cache the property lookup "method" (the "x.FirstName" bit could be handled via reflection pretty easily
2. Take a "selector" function and apply this to pickup the target object
3. Make this an extension method

Code:

```
public static class FilterPerson
{
    static IQueryable<Person> FilterPerson(
       this IQueryable<Person> query,
       FilterString filter,
       Func<Person, string> selector,
        string searchText)
    {
        var enumerableQuery = query.AsEnumerable();
        switch (filter)
        {
            case FilterString.Contains:
                enumerableQuery = enumerableQuery.Where(x => selector(x).ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant()));
                break;
            case FilterString.DoesNotContain:
                enumerableQuery = enumerableQuery.Where(x => !selector(x).ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower()));
                break;
            case FilterString.StartsWith:
                enumerableQuery = enumerableQuery.Where(x => selector(x).StartsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
            case FilterString.EndsWith:
                enumerableQuery = enumerableQuery.Where(x => selector(x).EndsWith(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
            case FilterString.Equals:
                enumerableQuery = enumerableQuery.Where(x => selector(x).Equals(searchText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
                break;
        }

        return enumerableQuery.AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

}

public enum FilterString
{
    StartsWith,
    Contains,
    DoesNotContain,
    EndsWith,
    Equals
}
```

Comment: No query provider will be able to translate that into SQL; they'll all error when you try to execute the query.

Comment: Example? Proof? He also didn't specify a need for SQL.

Comment: He's accepting an `IQueryable`.  If it were an in-memory collection it'd be an `IEnumerable`.  Even if it's not a database, and the `IQueryable` is in fact a representation for something else, the point remains that the query provider (at least any query provider other than the LINQ to objects query provider) won't be able to meaningfully translate this into anything else, because it's dependent on being able to execute `selector`.  If he were accepting an `IEnumerable`, then this would absolutely be a valid solution.

Comment: @Servy What if OP is just calling AsQueryable on his IEnumerables so he can iterate over them multiple times? :P

Comment: @moarboilerplate Why would he be calling `AsQueryable` on them?  Why not just treat them as `IEnumerable` objects instead?  Calling `AsQueryable` doesn't allow it to be iterated over repeatedly any more effectively than having an `IEnumerable`.  The point is that this answer would only ever work if the OP was actually passing in `IEnumerable` objects to which `AsQueryable` was called on them; unless he can verify that that's the case, the answer isn't valid.

Comment: So then roundtripping to IEnumerable would be valid (see latest edit.)

Comment: @MattClark That just *forces* the query to be evaluated in LINQ to Objects.  Presumably, if the OP has an `IQueryable,` they don't actually want the query to be executed in memory, they want the query to be translated into whatever the `IQueryable` wants to translate it into.  If they wanted it to be executed in memory then the method should accept an `IEnumerable`.  Calling `AsQueryable` again at the end and trying to translate it back is only making it all the more a lie as to what it's doing.  The method's signature *says* that it will work for any `IQueryable`, but in reality it doesn't.

Comment: @Servy Turns out OP was converting a sproc result set to an IQueryable, so 1) yes, that's exactly what he was doing, and 2) there's no need to be concerned about query providers

Comment: @moarboilerplate There's *every* reason to be concerned about query providers.  When you write code that compiles, but fails to actually function properly at runtime, that's *highly* concerning.  And what this method is doing now, where it's API gives the impression that it will be adding expressions to an `IQuerayble` that will be resolved by the query provider, and that will allow subsequent operations to be resolved by the query provider, but where it won't, is *extremely* misleading.  If the code isn't going to be translatable by a query provider, it's API should make that clear.

Comment: @Servy absolutely, I was limiting that statement to this example and not making a blanket statement. So taking a step back, this new information makes all of the answers on here (well, maybe not mine for different reasons) legitimate, but they're all downvoted and a query provider is now a giant red herring. Are you saying that this is all the fault of the question not providing enough information?

Comment: @moarboilerplate The question that is actually asked here has an answer that actually answers the question asked correctly, and that answer is the only answer with a positive score.  The answers that all incorrectly answer the question that was actually asked have a negative score.  Sounds like everything is exactly as it should be.  Had the OP actually asked about how to perform this operation on an `IEnumerable`, not an `IQueryable`, it would of course change the correct answer(s).

Comment: @Servy you've hit on the crux of the issue. There's a distinct difference between what OP (intentionally or unintentionally) purports to need, and what OP's use case calls for. Shall we continue this on meta?

Answer (score -5):

If it's called 6 times in your code, and there are 5 paths inside it, I'd say the method itself is introducing unnecessary coupling and should be removed.

Comment: yes, I am a junior dev, just looking for some assistance

Comment: I would totally remove this method and have your code directly use the LINQ queries. There's no reason except for far more complex scenarios to put an abstraction layer over LINQ.

Comment: The question is specifically asking how to remove it; you are providing no guidance as to how to go about doing that.

Comment: @moarboilerplate The queries aren't static, so statically defining the queries isn't going to be an option.

Comment: What you are suggesting should be a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: @Servy Reread the question. OP is not asking how to remove it, he's asking how to make 5 other methods that look the exact same dynamic so he can pass in a property reference.

Comment: this really should be a comment regardless.. what you have stated as an answer provides zero direction to the `OP` as well as others in regards to demonstrating a workable / viable answer

Comment: Look at the question. OP wants to put a layer over LINQ that lets him "query" with strings. Is this a pattern that SO users are in favor of?

Comment: @MethodMan That's because OP should remove this whole layer and put the LINQ queries back in his consuming code.

Comment: @moarboilerplate When I said "remove it" was was referring to what you proposed removing in your answer, namely the coupling.  If you want to remove the coupling from this code, show him how to do it.  As for ways of making EF queries more dynamic, there are appropriate and inappropriate ways of doing it in my experiences.  Some types of things can be made dynamic effectively, and some can't.

Comment: @moarboilerplate I think you are missing the point.  OP isn't calling that one method in six places. OP has six similar methods, but each queries a different property on the object in question.

Comment: @Pedro What he'd *like* to have is one method that he could call in 6 different places.

Comment: My point is that this whole set of 6 methods shouldn't exist at all, or as one unified method. It should be totally deleted. And if we are assuming OP is using strings to enhance EF queries, any enhancement to data access via strings would be happening down a layer, not a layer on top of the LINQ.

Comment: @moarboilerplate And if you were able to demonstrate how he could do that and still solve the problem that he's trying to solve, that could be a fine answer.  But you didn't, which is why this isn't a good answer.

Comment: @Servy are you suggesting asking OP to provide a sample of how he's calling this method so I can inline it and post it as an answer? Because that's the only answer that I can give that "demonstrates" deleting it.

Comment: @moarboilerplate If you'd just be literally inclining it, how would that *possibly* help?  Having the code repeated 6 times in line would be even *worse* than having 6 of these methods.  Having a single method that takes in all of the relevant data and constructs the query is *absolutely* worthwhile.  Again, the queries aren't static.  Inlining the dynamic code 6 different times is not productive.

Comment: @Servy I feel like you're missing my entire point. OP should have *zero* methods abstracting his LINQ calls. The whole point of this layer is to implement querying an IQueryable with strings using a custom syntax. Yeah, that's what OP asked for, but I'm trying to say "you should not be writing this type of code."

Comment: @moarboilerplate And that's assuming the entirety of the query is statically known, which it's *not*.  So he *couldn't* do that.

Comment: @Servy see my comment on your answer re: whether OP really needs what he's asking for